# How can I shift the index of a DataFrame when using Float64Index?

Tags: python, pandas

As the question mentions, I have a pandas (v. 0.18.0) dataframe which consists of a few columns of 1D data (simulated optical spectra).

A sample dataset looks like the following:

```
Photon Energy (eV),  Spin_Up (a.u.),  Spin_Down (a.u.),       Difference  
1.520040,                  0.000000,           0.00000,         0.000000   
1.520515,                  0.000000,           0.00000,         0.000000   
1.520990,                  0.000000,           0.00000,         0.000000   
1.521465,                  9.742188,           0.00000,         9.742188   
1.521940,                 35.432140,          24.41665,        11.015490   
1.522415,                 69.708160,          99.48898,       -29.780820   
1.522890,                140.897400,         198.71710,       -57.819700   
1.523365,                369.593200,         401.61710,       -32.023900   
1.523840,               1688.481000,        1034.93300,       653.548000   
1.524315,               1822.535000,        4645.04600,     -2822.511000   
1.524790,               1284.102000,        5457.34800,     -4173.246000
```

The data are imported directly from a CSV (`pd.read_csv('sample.csv', index_col='Photon Energy (eV)')`, and the three imported columns are an index row (photon energy with six decimal precision) and two electron populations (integer values).

Now, I'd like to shift the index column by ~2.5meV (corresponding to 200 rows).

I've pulled the max point with the following:

```
abs_max = df.loc[1.52:1.53,["Sum"]].idxmax()
shift_idx = df.index.get_loc(abs_max[0])
shift_amt = int(shift_idx - spdf.index.get_loc(1.515005))
```

then tried to apply the shift with `df.shift(periods=shift_amt)` (I realize the `int()` on `shift_amt` is unnecessary, just trying to cover all the bases). This seemed to have no effect (index column was unshifted). Trying to apply a value to `freq` inside the `shift()` function made no difference. When I tried the same thing using `df.index.shift()`, I was given an error `NotImplementedError: Not supported for type Float64Index`. I assume this means that what I'm trying to do isn't possible, and that I should go back to using a simple integer index column. But, before I give up, I'd like to know if there is something I'm missing in this process.

Comment: [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) says you must use `int` for periods.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to define `shift_amt` in my question. It _is_ an integer, so I don't think that's an issue.

Comment: what do you mean saying to shift index? are you after `df.index += 0.5`?

Comment: I suppose that would work… actually going for -=.0025, but that might produce the desired effect. I'll give it a shot in the morning and report back.

Comment: `df.index += x` works well for this ( and is probably more appropriate, since you don't have to worry about dropping values at the top or bottom of the series). If you want to turn it into an answer, I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can change your index values like this:

```
df.index += x
```